# How to define the conditional probability table of $D$ which depends on $A$, $B$ and $C$?

Tags: probability, bayesian-network

$A$, $B$ and $C$ are independent variables. The probabilities of occurrence are taken as contribution percentage on the variable $D$. The probability of occurrence of $D$ is known. I found on a master thesis a way for calculating CPTs for $D$ but did not find a formula or interpretation for it. How was the calculation made based on the information in the image?

Here letter $T$ represents the occurrence and letter $F$ represents the opposite.

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{array}{l}
P(A = T) = 0.3\\
P(B = T) = 0.3\\
P(C = T) = 0.4\\
P(D = T) \text{ is known}
\end{array} \qquad \begin{CD}
@. B\\
@. @VVV\\
A @>>> D @<<< C
\end{CD}
$$$$
\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|}\hline
P(A) & P(B) & P(C) & P(D = T) & P(D = F)\\\hline
T & T & T & P(A = T) + P(B = T) + P(C = T) = 1 & 1 - 1 = 0\\\hline
F & T & T & P(B = T) + P(C = T) = 0.7 & 1 - 0.7 = 0.3\\\hline
T & F & T & P(A = T) + P(C = T) = 0.7 & 1 - 0.7 = 0.3\\\hline
F & F & T & P(C = T) = 0.4 & 1 - 0.4 = 0.6\\\hline
T & T & F & P(A = T) + P(B = T) = 0.6 & 0.4\\\hline
F & T & F & P(B = T) = 0.3 & 0.7\\\hline
T & F & F & P(A = T) = 0.3 & 0.7\\\hline
F & F & F & 0 & 1\\\hline
\end{array}\\
\text{Conditional probability table of node } D
$$